# Struts 2 property not being read from properties file

Tags: properties, struts2, formatting

After following the struts 2 web pages and numerous examples, my application still will not pick up values from the struts.properties file.

I am trying this in order to give some values a money type format:

```
<s:property value="getText('struts.money.format',{value})" />
```

My struts.properties file which is under WEB-INF/classes and therefore visible has the following single line

```
struts.money.format= {0,number,\u00A4##0.00}
```

I get the string `struts.money.format` printed to the screen.  If I change the first parameter of the getText call, the new string I put also will get printed instead of a true lookup happening.

If I do `<s:property value="value" />` I will get back a proper number.  If I drop the second argument on the getText call, I would expect to get back the right hand side of the assignment in the properties file, but i get the same `struts.money.format` back.

I am using Tomcat 6 with Struts 2.2.1.1.  Is there an additional part of the puzzle I am possibly leaving out?

Comment: Can you provide an example for how do you want to format the values? we can do it message resource bundle.

Comment: Once I get the formatting in place something like $5,215.21 or -$1,740.86.  Eventually, I will need to make the negative values red text.  I would like to figure out the why isn't my struts.properties being seen/used though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in my struts.xml file, I put this line

```
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="struts" />
```

It needs this to know that I am trying to use a struts.properties file.  I had assumed that by default a file named struts.properties was along the chain of places to look for a constant such as this.  Only if you named it something else did you need to specify that.  Even though it is in WEB-INF/classes which is recommended by the Struts 2 documentation, it just simply was not looking in this file.

**EDIT**

For what it is worth, I also had to modify my struts text tag like so

```
<s:property value="getText('struts.money.format',{@java.lang.Double@valueOf(value)})" />
```

Actually, `value` should have been a BigDecimal, but it was being treated at the view level here as java.lang.String.  The problem is that some of the String objects had exponential formatting (like 1.642E07 or something to that effect) and the struts formatter could not handle the exponential formatting.  The valueOf eliminates this exponential fomatting